# Customer chat not working with React Messenger Customer Chat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, chat, facebook-chat

I would like to integrate the Facebook customer chat plugin in a React web application.

App runs in development mode on the URL: *http://localhost:3000/*

Used npm package: *react-messenger-customer-chat*

Created a new Facebook App and Facebook Site with the same name, and connected them in Facebook for Developers.

Stored the *App ID* and the *Page ID* on the React side.

Added in Settings -> Basic -> *App Domains: localhost* (typed in "http://localhost:3000/ but was saved as "localhost"

Added a new platform -> *Website: http://localhost:3000/*

Whitelisted on the Messenger Platform -> Advanced Settings -> *Whitelisted Domains: http://127.0.0.1:3000/, https://127.0.0.1:3000/, https://127.0.0.1:3000/, https://127.0.0.1/*

Set up the React code, passed in the arguments to the new component. After reloading, I get a 200 response from Facebook but an empty div is shown in the site, and I could not manage to make it work (even tried with pure Javascript scripts or created a Test App).

*Used in App.js:*

```
import React from 'react';
import MessengerCustomerChat from 'react-messenger-customer-chat';

import { FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID } from '../../shared/configuration';

const Chat = (props) => (
  <div>
    <MessengerCustomerChat pageId={FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID} appId={FACEBOOK_APP_ID} />
  </div>
);

export default Chat;
```

**Request URL:**

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.11/plugins/customerchat.php?app_id=<MY_APP_APP_ID>&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fx%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2F%3Fversion%3D46%23cb%3Df197f00e47470a%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Ff229f87298f7008%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=0&locale=en_US&page_id=MY_APP_PAGE_ID>&request_time=1603379771509&sdk=joey
```

**Response header:**

```
alt-svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=3600,h3-27=":443"; ma=3600
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
content-encoding: br
content-security-policy: default-src * data: blob: 'self';script-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob: data: 'self';style-src data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' *;connect-src *.facebook.com facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:* wss://*.facebook.com:* https://fb.scanandcleanlocal.com:* attachment.fbsbx.com ws://localhost:* blob: *.cdninstagram.com 'self' chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm;block-all-mixed-content;upgrade-insecure-requests;
content-security-policy: frame-ancestors https://www.facebook.com;
content-type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
date: Thu, 22 Oct 2020 15:16:11 GMT
expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
facebook-api-version: v8.0
pragma: no-cache
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; preload
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-fb-debug: 3hcF+KdxLlfSCdNr3qJFo24n/o8y1GyMJRbFbyeBdoZdhniyI8ummvUQAGY6KB8GAdDePynl83js0QmsH6a5xA==
x-xss-protection: 0
```

**HTML code** (first 'div' should be the 'Chat' component content, other two rows are injected by the npm package):
[image]

*What can be the solution for this issue?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domain name as "localhost" is not an option when developing and testing a React application with the Facebook Chat Plugin.

1. In the operation system hosts file have to add a new entry, for example: *127.0.0.1 react-with-chat-app.com*
2. On Windows run command prompt as administrator with *ipconfig /flushdns* command.
3. Add *.env* file in the root of the React project, and add your new hostname: *HOST=react-with-chat-app.com*
4. Add *http://react-with-chat.com/* to the Facebook Site whitelist domains array, and change the Facebook App's website also to *http://react-with-chat.com/*.
5. Restart React application, and access using: *http://react-with-chat-app.com:3000*, and test the chat functionality.